# Arquillian - How to debug managed Wildfly container

Tags: testing, tdd, jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian to write black box tests for my RESTful application. I am actually capable of debug the test classes, but unable to debug my application classes. I would like to know exactly how to do that.

My arquillian.xml:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
<container qualifier="jbossas-managed" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="jbossHome">D:\desenv\arquivos\servidores\wildfly-9.0.1.Final-test</property>
        <property name="allowConnectingToRunningServer">true</property>
        <property name="javaVmArguments">-Dorg.apache.deltaspike.ProjectStage=IntegrationTest</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

One of my test classes:

```
@RunAsClient
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class AuthenticationBlackBoxTest extends AbstractBlackBoxTest {

    @Test
    public void testInvalidCredentials(@ArquillianResource URL baseURI) {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(baseURI.toString()).path("api/v1/auth");
         Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .post(Entity.entity(new Credentials("invalid", "invalid"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        Assert.assertEquals(401, response.getStatus());
        response.close();
        client.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidCredentials(@ArquillianResource URL baseURI) {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(baseURI.toString()).path("api/v1/auth");
        Entity<Credentials> credentialsEntity = Entity.entity(new Credentials("adm@adm.com", "123"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .post(credentialsEntity);

        Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        response.close();
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: remote debug is your friend here.

Comment: Can you tell me more about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside arquillian.xml for javaVmArguments element add `-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y`.

Then in your favourite IDE you have to define a new Remote Debug configuration where you specify the host(localhost), port(8787). Place your break point, then run your test and finally start the remote debug. Official doc [here](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started_rinse_and_repeat/#debug_a_managed_server).

Comment: Thanks for you collaboration @Franck. Btw could you provide a more detailed answer? I don't have a standalone.conf file anywhere. I am using InteliJ as IDE

Comment: I am sorry I've just edited the response. I did not realize your are in the managed case.

Comment: I am having trouble to configure the remote debug configuration.. Can we chat?

Comment: yes, please ping me I am not familiar with the option

Comment: I managed to do it. Thanks for your time. I used your answer and some info from this blog to achieve my goal

http://techilashots.blogspot.com.br/2015/04/debugging-using-wildfly-and-arquillian.html

Comment: Ok, I use myself arq in remote mode that explains my confusion. But the official answer is in the arq guide itself [here](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started_rinse_and_repeat/#debug_a_managed_server). Response edited as well.

Comment: Likely, you want to user suspend=n at the end for the server not to wait for a debugger to connect. This way, it will also work on a CI server like Jenkins. suspend=y seemes only reasonable to me if you want to debug the startup phase.

Comment: In case you have a container managed by arquillian, it is important to have suspend=y, otherwise you could miss your debug breakpoints